# angularjs - ng-model filter by object index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an api that I am calling like this:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/people',
  headers: {
    'Accept' : "application/json; charset=utf-8"  
},
}).then(function successCallback(data) {
     $scope.camps = data.data;
  }, function errorCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
   });
});
```

and an `ng-repeat` that I am calling like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="camp in camps | filter:search:strict  track by $index">
     <tile></tile>
</div>
```

and a piece of code in my html that is creating an input:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
     <label>Stage</label>
     <input ng-model="search.status_history.status">
</md-input-container>
```

As you can see from the last portion of code, the `ng-model` is doing a filter of `search.status_history.status`, this is technically working but it is filtering all the endpoints in the api...

`status_history` looks like this:

```
"status_history": [
  {
    "status": "ideation",
  },
  {
    "status": "build",
  }
],
```

How would I do it that I only filter the last status entry in `status_history`? I tried

```
<input ng-model="search.status_history[search.status_history.length-1].status">
```

but this breaks it... Is there any way I can filter the last entry? Thank you.

Comment: Create a custom filter

Comment: @charlietfl How would that work with my current filter?